# How can I fix "Undefined variable from import: objects" in Aptana pydev django mongo-engine?

Tags: django, pydev, mongoengine

Aptana 3(pydev), django 1.3 + mongo-engine0.5.2
My pythonpath is current, interpreter also works well.
But when I try to make a Document object:

```
class IdCount(Document):
    model_name = StringField(max_length = 30)
```

When I use "IdCount.objects", it can't work well, and show me "Undefined variable from import: objects".
But the "." can show other variables and classes, like pk(), save(), model_name, etc.
Btw, when I use command line mode (django->shell),it works well.
How can I fix this error?
Changing editor option can ignore this error, but I want to resolve it.

Comment: It seems the static analyzer is not recognizing your code... What is the class Document? Can you put the code with imports in the question?

Comment: Fabio, this is the class in question:
https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/document.py I'm currently experiencing the same problem using mongoengine 0.5.2

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding "mongoengine" to Forced Builtins? (Properties > PyDev - interpreter/grammer > Configure interpreter > Forced Builtins)

Comment: it worked. But now I am getting Unresolved import error for 'from mongoengine.django.auth import User'